# mySQL SQL joined table then find rows with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: 
**Orders**

```
orders_ID
orderDate
```

**Order Details**

```
product_ID
order_ID
quantity
```

**Products**

```
product_ID
productName
productDescription
```

I want to find all the records in the Order Details of product_ID 1 and 4 (so trying to see when one order contains both of these products). So ran this code - the INNER JOIN creates a results table that contains only orders that contain product 1, 4, or 1 and 4.

Then I want to count all of the "Order Details".order_ID duplicates - these would be all of the orders that contain 1 and 4 (note- trivial database - a given order doesn't contain more than 1 of any product).

Here is my code - doesn't quite work - any thoughts?

```
SELECT order_ID, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM Orders o INNER JOIN "Order Details" od ON o.order_ID = od.order_ID
      WHERE od.product_ID = 1 OR od.product_ID = 4)
GROUP BY order_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Thanks- I looked through the forum but didn't see anything that helped me - been trying for some time.

Comment: "a given order doesn't contain more than 1 of any product)." - of course it doesn't; that's your PRIMARY KEY!

Comment: I was't clear. For each order in Orders, there can be none to many 'Order Items' rows. I want to know how many orders have products 1 and 2. Each order can only have 0 or 1 products.

Comment: Very hard to follow, by providing some sample data by editing your post would help.  Also, for clarification... do you want all order that have BOTH products?  Or, as you stated 1, the other, or both... they are different queries.  Also, your final count.. do you want the total number of items ON THE ORDER? or just the count that matched the criteria you were looking for.  Finally, why have an order that has no products on it... totally does not make any sense.

Comment: Soeey. Ultimately I want both. The other was an intermediate step.

Comment: Sorry. Ultimately I want both. The other was an intermediate step. The order_ID are product_ID are both AI integers. So you might have order_IDs of 1, 2, 3, etc. There are four product_IDs 1, 2, 3, 4. One order, say order_ID 1 could have 3 records in the 'Order Details' table: product_IDs 1, 2, and 4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a JOIN:

```
select prod1.order_id from `Order Details` prod1 JOIN  `Order Details` prod4 on prod1.order_ID=prod2.order_ID where prod1.product_ID=1 and prod2.product_ID=4;
```

Comment: This didn't work - it said it could not find the column.

Comment: What column wasn't found? It looks like either you or I mistyped orders_id. Can you paste the exact error message (and the exact real query)?

Comment: I did a couple adjustments and this worked perfectly! (typo prod4 should be prod2) - THANKS!!